# Multiple Inheritance for RMI unicodeRemoteObject

Tags: java, rmi

I am tring to write server side code for Remote Method Invocation.
I am writing a **"rmiServer"** class that is a class on server.
This class is already extending another class.
Now, I want to extend this class with **"unicodeRemoteObject"** class.
but the problem is that java didn't allow multiple inheritance,
So How can I do this?

Comment: Here's some reading for you: http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/compoinh.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to extend `UnicastRemoteObject.` Instead, in your constructor, call `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject().` The effect is the same.